# Quick way to perform this entry-wise operation on matrices in R?

Tags: r

Suppose I have two matrices:
A of size n by m, and B of size n by 2.

I would like to obtain a matrix C of size n by m, so that
C[i,j] = A[i,j] * B[i,2] + B[i,1].

How can I do that easily and quickly in R? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
R>A <- matrix(1:20,5,4)
R>A
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    6   11   16
[2,]    2    7   12   17
[3,]    3    8   13   18
[4,]    4    9   14   19
[5,]    5   10   15   20

R>B <- matrix(1:10,5,2)
R>B
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    6
[2,]    2    7
[3,]    3    8
[4,]    4    9
[5,]    5   10

R>A * B[,2] + B[,1]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    7   37   67   97
[2,]   16   51   86  121
[3,]   27   67  107  147
[4,]   40   85  130  175
[5,]   55  105  155  205
```

Comment: Thanks! Is `A * B[,2]` matrix times vector? If not, how do you do matrix times vector?

Comment: Matrix multiply is `A %*% B[,2]`